# Generating a pdf, and sending it to user with using HttpServletResponse(headers)

Tags: java, struts2, pdf-generation, httpresponse

Welcome all.
I'm trying to create a PDF to send to user, without saving the file on my server first.
I'm using Hibernate + struts2.
My samples code: 
`CreatePDF.java` (Class for generate pdf)
Method `BuildPdf():`

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try {
    document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document,baos);
    document.open();
    buildPage(document, snippet, snippetContent);
    document.close();
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.setContentLength(baos.size());
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=document.pdf");
    ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    baos.writeTo(out);
    out.flush();
    response.flushBuffer();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log4jUtil.debug(logger, "Can not buid pdf-file", e);
}
```

My sample action:
method index():

```
pdf = new CreatePDF();
pdf.buildPdf(snippet, snippetContent);
return SUCCESS;
```

Can you check my code please for search error? Could there be errors....
Please help me. Need ideas, or example code to solve my task.

Comment: "sending user PDF don't save in server machine" what does this mean? and are you flushing the content yourself as visible from your code?

Comment: sorry, bad speak English...Sending a PDF to the user without saving on server. Can now understand, what written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Hibernate is fully irrelevant here. Struts2 is relevant, but you are not using it, you are using plain (low level) servlet API. That should probably work, but if your webapp is built around Struts2, that's not the recommended way. You should instead use the [Stream result](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/stream-result.html)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I meant that my application is built on these technologies.
I'm done with persistence to the server and use the Stream result. Everything works fine. But I want to be that I would not save data files to the server.
I suggested the idea to send a file using thread and headers. So I'm trying to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

For creating PDF documents, you can use Smart PDF Creator. It creates professional PDFs in a couple of clicks. You can try it for free here: http://www.smartpdfcreator.com

Comment: Does this allow you to pass the document via code? From what I can see on visiting this, I do not think it can.

Comment: Thank you, Can you understand question ? I'm creating PDF, but can't sending it to user.